# Can a varying quantity be added to a fixed quantity

Tags: electric-current, vectors, voltage

I saw a statement saying that a direct current of a units can be superimposed with an alternating current of bsin(wt) but this seems a bit contradicting as one quantity is continuously varying will other is constant. It seems like adding speed to velocity.  So is there a way I can convince myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sort of current variation with a DC offset is often found in electronic circuits.

[image]

In terms of the motion of a particle imagine the motion a simple pendulum with the equilibrium position of the bob being at $0$ on a ruler.
The thick black line represents the position of the bob as read off from the scale on the ruler (red scale) .

Now move the ruler so that the equilibrium position of the bob is at $0.5$ on the ruler.
The thick black line represents the position of the bob as read off from the scale on the ruler (black scale) in its new position.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. It is just shifting the current up to a constant. Think of a graph with current against time, but the sinusoidal wave is just shifted upward.

Comment: How are we gonna add

Comment: At each instant of time you add the dc component to the value of alternating current at that instant.